# Can't read achievements for certain users

Tags: facebook-graph-api, achievements

I'm experiencing some inconsistent behaviour when trying to read achievements from my app. I have 3 tests accounts, 2 of which I can read achievements. However the 3rd account always returns an empty array. All 3 accounts have the publish_action permission and I've tried using both the user and app access_token. Here's the query:

https://graph.facebook.com/{uid}/achievements?access_token={app_access_token}

or

https://graph.facebook.com/{uid}/achievements?access_token={user_access_token}

Now I know the 3rd account has achievements as I get an error when I try to give it an achievement it already has and the game ticker correctly shows the achievements it has earned.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the third user has granted "user_activities" extended permissions so that the activities can be read, not just published.  You can verify this by calling /me/permissions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. None of the 3 accounts had user_activities and from the documentation only publish_actions is needed to create/read/delete achievements. None the less I added user_activities to test out your theory, we all know Facebook documentation is never accurate, but had no luck. I still can't read earned achievements on the 3rd account.

Comment: Also try this permission: user_games_activity. Also call /me/permissions with that account to verify the permissions are still in place.

Comment: user_games_activity didn't help either. Account has the proper permissions, that's something I've checked over and over. I can give that account any achievement without a hitch, just can't read them afterwards. I also confirmed permissions were correct with an FQL query.

Comment: It's sounds like a bug with Facebook then, especially if two other accounts work with the exact same permissions and the 3rd account can post.  I would log it at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: I have already, let's hope they get back to me. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the facebook layout regarding achievements in your app? since in my FB account I can roll over my own achievements and I get a full list of the achievements configured with each game and in other acocunt that info is not available. The other distinctive feature is I see my thumbnail picture over the main facebook bar (the blue one next to log in)